# Audio resources for an amateur live-sound guy

Tags: live

I am self learned live sound guy. I know some basics but want to expand my knowledge. I don't use any compressors, or gates, and very few effects but would like to. I also would like to know some more of the basics like why and how to properly adjust EQ per channel/overall, why and what mics to use for different applications. I have not done any studio but would like to learn.

What are some resources (books, online videos, classes, etc) for understanding more of the basics and advanced techniques for Live sound? Anything that translate to Studio would be helpful also.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Sound on Sound magazine](http://soundonsound.com/) for learning about effects and microphones. It is more studio focused than live sound, but you'll learn a lot. You have to pay to read the latest issues, but you can read all issues in their [back catalogue](http://soundonsound.com/AllIssues.php) over 6 months old for free.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you may also want to get the mother of all pro sound tomes: The Yamaha Sound Reinforcement Handbook.

Answer (score 1):

[Mastering Audio](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240808371) by Bob Katz gets a lot of recommendations. I can't comment further as I haven't ordered my copy yet!

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason not to jump in with both feet, especially if it's free. Subscribe to [TapeOP](http://www.tapeop.com/subscriptions/), which is absolutely free. It's a bit challenging to read since the layout is a bit unconventional, but you will get opinions and reviews from real engineers and producers that really work with the gear (as opposed to journalists and "pro" reviewers). did I mention it's [free](http://www.tapeop.com/subscriptions/)?